# wp_query display posts from same category of the post

Tags: wp-query, categories

On my post page I am trying to display list of other posts from the same category of the original post. So far I got this and this does not seem to work:

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'article',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ),
        'category'     => array( get_the_category() ),
        'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                    'key' => 'recommended_article',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '=='
                        )
                    )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

    <?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<a class="popup-article-picture" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="background-image: url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>');"></a>
<a class="popup-article-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Is this within the loop for the main post?  Is the built-in taxonomy `category` attached to your custom post type?  Are there any articles in the same category with meta value `recommended_article == 1`? When you say it doesn't work, what are you expecting to see and how do you judge that it's not working as it should?

Comment: @Andy This loop is within template page for custom post type article. recommended_article == 1 allows me to filter posts that I mark recommended with true/false thingy from ACF.

Comment: There isn't anywhere near enough information to help you.  Can you show more of the template file concerned?  Can you show where you have attached Categories to the CPT `article`?

Comment: @Andy, i used Custom Post Types UI to create custom post type and attach it to exisiting WP categories, the loop is inside single-article.php in my template. I am very new at PHP and wordpress so that about as much as I can tell really.

Comment: Thanks - just eliminating possible basic problems. I think we need to see the whole template, if you can edit your question to include it.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook how do you want me to show it to you? The whole template is pretty big. Or you just need to see single-article.php?

Comment: That file is the template, so yes, but possibly any files it includes. I can edit the question to remove irrelevant bits to shorten it.

Comment: @Andy [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gtel5vfc6lkx20w/Archive.zip?dl=0) I included functions.php but i don't think there's anything important there

Comment: Thanks - would I be right in saying that the main article doesn't display?  For example, where you have used `the_title()` nothing happens? Can I see header.php?

Comment: @Andy Here you go [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k1fa8jht9fy3svm/header.php?dl=0). Nope, everything else up until the category issue works perfectly for me

Comment: @Andy I've found a solution on my own. Thank you for tryin' to help!

Comment: Cool!  No problem. Write your solution as an answer and accept it as the correct one. That keeps the format of the site tidy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found an answer:

```
<?php

    $cats = get_the_category();
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'article',
        'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ),
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'cat'     => $cats[0]->term_id,
        'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                    'key' => 'recommended_article',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '=='
                        )
                    )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>  

<?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>   

<!--HTML-->

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: not working now :(

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to query the custom post type called `article`. are you using default WordPress post categories for post type `article`? or have registered any custom taxonomy for that post type? i assume you are using default WordPress category for `CPT`. 
so first step is to get the current category from single page. following function will return categories attached to the post from outside the loop.

```
get_the_category();
```

it will return an array of term objects. and you have to get the slug from this array to pass in the query.
lets assume we have only one category assigned for single post.

```
$category_obj = get_the_category();
$category = $category_obj[0]->slug;
```

now you can use that in your related posts query.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'article',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'category'     => $category,
        'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                    'key' => 'recommended_article',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '=='
                        )
                    )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

and if you are using custom taxonomy for post type then let us know so we can help you regarding custom taxonomies.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what exactly do i need to with that piece of code? Simply adding it to the template didn't work for me. Thank you!